# Android app: Actual and Formal Argument lists differ in length error

Tags: android

Possibly an easy fix but I can't find the issue. I am receiving the following error on starting my android application:

```
error: constructor MenuList in class MenuList cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String,String,String
found: String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I don't understand why it is finding only two string parameters though as I am passing 4 through, here is my code:

The MenuList class:

```
public class MenuList {
    String ID, Name, AvailableFrom, AvailableTo;

    public MenuList(String ID, String name, String availableFrom, String availableTo) {
        this.ID = ID;
        Name = name;
        AvailableFrom = availableFrom;
        AvailableTo = availableTo;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getAvailableFrom() {
        return AvailableFrom;
    }

    public String getAvailableTo() {
        return AvailableTo;
    }
}
```

And then the Menu class itself:

```
public class Menus extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    List<MenuList> listMenus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menus);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.list_menu);
        listMenus = new ArrayList<>();
        showList();
}
private void showList(){
        String url = "hidden";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("menus");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        final JSONObject menuObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        MenuList m = new MenuList(menuObj.getString("menu_id"), menuObj.getString("menu_name"), menuObj.getString("available_from"), menuObj.getString("available_to"));
                        listMenus.add(m);

                }MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(listMenus, getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){

        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }
```

There is no error within the php file, it works as expected. The error has resulted in me trying to extend the menu list to four parameters (it used to be two and worked fine) but I can't figure out why it didn't work after extending it

Comment: well there is no error in above code...try invalidate cache if it help

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: I copied your code in my android studio and it's fine... You getting this error on complie time right?

Comment: Yea, upon trying to run the application I get the error strangely.

Answer (score 0):

Woops!

Found out that the MenuList was actually being used on another activity too and this is where the error was coming from!